# Is there a feature flag I can test in .vimrc to tell whether I am running VsVim?

Tags: vsvim

In `.vimrc`, I can test whether I am loaded in GVim by testing for `has('gui_running')`. Is there a similar feature flag that VsVim uses so I can test whether VsVim is currently running?

The reason is that there are some mappings that I use in regular Vim that cause problems when run within VsVim and so I'd like to avoid loading them when run inside VsVim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, I found a workaround by using a `~/.vsvimrc` file. I just set a `has_vsvim` variable in `.vsvimrc`, then source my normal `.vimrc` file, in which I can check for the `has_vsvim` flag.

**~/.vsvimrc:**

```
let has_vsvim = 1
so ~/dotfiles/.vimrc
```

**~/dotfiles/.vimrc**

```
" ...snip...
if !exists('has_vsvim')
    " ... perform actions that shouldn't happen in VsVim ...
endif
" ...snip...
```